# Intellij "java: package org.junit does not exist" and "org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class"

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to setup Junit to an existing git project and ran into those following issues
Intellij "java: package org.junit does not exist" and "org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class"

I figured out the Solutions below:

Answer (score 0):

First create a test in intellji by clicking on the class and do the following:

1. Windows: Control N =>generate=>Test
2. Mac: command-N => generate=>Test
3. Select the version of junit
   Your settings should look similar to this:
   [image]

Now you have Junit installed correctly.

To fix the **"java: package org.junit does not exist"** 
**Make sure you create a Test directory same level as src package "not inside"**

To fix  **"org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class"**

- make sure the **"Module setting"** look like the following:

[image]

if this helps Press upvote: